# "Invalid pointer operation" ao criar data module

Tags: delphi

tenho uma dll feita em delphi 2010, e as vezes ocorre o erro de "Invalid pointer operation" ao criar o data module, o qual contém componentes de conexão dbexpress (simpledataset, sqlconnection, clientdataset, etc, assim como alguns componentes do rave report). A dll funciona 90% das vezes, mas vez ou outra gera o erro.

A aplicação que chama afunção da dll tb é feita em delphi 2010. Pesquisei bastante no google, mas nunca vi dar esse erro ao criar um data module, geralmente o pessoal encontra esse erro ao dar um .free ou ao sair da aplicação, mas no meu caso é ao CRIAR data module.

Já tentei colocar o SimpleShareMem como 1a. declaração do uses, tanto no fonte da dll como no fonte do exe que chama ela, mesmo erro...

Ocorre assim:

- aplicação inicia e chama função da DLL, funciona normal, fecho a aplicação
- aplicação inicia e chama função da DLL, funciona normal, fecho a aplicação
- aplicação inicia e chama função da DLL, **ERRO**, fecho a aplicação
- aplicação inicia e chama função da DLL, funciona normal, fecho a aplicação
- e assim vai...

As mensagens não são sempre iguais, isso que me intriga:

- invalid pointer operation, OU
- error reading sqlTable1FIELD1.FieldName: invalid pointer operation, OU
- error reading sqlTable1FIELD1.SQLConnection: property 0RAVECOMPLETED does not exist
- Class TSmallIntField not found

Alguma sugestão?

```
function Imp1(vEmp: Integer): boolean; export; stdcall;
var Registry: TRegistry;
begin
  with dmNFD2 do
  begin
    try
      p_NumEmp := vEmp;
      result := True;
      if not(Assigned(dmNFD2)) then
         //Application.CreateForm(TdmNFD2,dmNFD2); // erro aqui ou
         dmNFD2 := TdmNFD2.Create(nil); // erro aqui
      if not(dmNFD2.sqlConn.Connected) then
      begin
        ConnectBD; // le o registro do windows (path, user e password database)
      end;
      if dmNFD2.sqlConn.Connected then
      begin
        qryGen.Close;
        qryGen.SQL.Text := 'select CAMPO from TABELA where PARNUM = :PARNUM';
        qryGen.Params.ParamByName('PARNUM').AsInteger := p_NumEmp;
        qryGen.Open;
        // insert or update in other table
        // ....
      end;     
    except
      on e:Exception do
      begin
        result := False;
      end; 
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Por acaso a aplicação que usa esse data module é multi thread? O problema com data modules já nasce no seu conceito: um monte de objetos globais que dependem de manutenção constante de estado. Além disso, você tem duas linhas criando instância de *TdmNFD2* para a mesma variáel (embora uma das linhas esteja comentada). Outra coisa: verificar se a variável é *Assigned* não garante que ela referencie uma instância válida; ela pode conter sujeira por não ter sido inicializada com *nil* ou pelo objeto outrora referenciado ali já ter sido destruído.

Comment: Caffé, o data module está dentro de uma dll, o qual não utiliza threads. Há 2 linhas pra criação do data module pq eu estava testando um ou outro (pesquisei e vi que é mais seguro usar "nil").

Comment: @MTeste tenta usar tambem o `Self`, geralmente é melhor que o `nil`

Comment: A questão não é se o datamodule usa threads mas sim se o consumidor do datamodule utiliza threads ao consumi-lo.

Comment: Não usa threads ao usar função da dll.